# why I am getting this exception [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]

Tags: java, spring

**SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.clearCache()V**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
  <display-name>Product</display-name>
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
                   /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
           </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.home.*"></context:component-scan> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"    location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**"   location="/WEB-INF/resources/images/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**"      location="/WEB-INF/resources/css/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**"        location="/WEB-INF/resources/fonts/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**"       location="/WEB-INF/resources/js/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/view/**"       location="/view/" />
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  </beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
    <property name="username" value="system"></property>
    <property name="password" value="admin"></property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="show_format">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.home.*</value>           
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: What is your Spring Framework's version?

Comment: I am using a Spring 4.3.0 version.